# How do you translate: she's very fancy

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning

Fancy as she dresses well, fashionable or is good decorating, etc.

Comment: you use a translator to translate, thats how. try Google's

Comment: Google Translator didn't give a correct answer. It shows "她非常喜欢。".

Comment: It seems that Google doesn't translate the subtleties of language unless you need a literal translation

Comment: "花俏" seems not a common word in Mandarin. I find it in my little dictionary, and post it in the answer below. Still looking for a better exlaination. Anyone can help?

Comment: fancy： (in a positive way):时髦，潮, (in a negative way) 花哨

Comment: @T-Pioneer we use 花哨 a lot, which means unnecessarily over-decorated.

Answer (score 1):

**fancy** *adj.* `not simple or ordinary` 复杂的；花巧的；精致的(From *"Oxford Elementary Learner's English-Chinese Dictionary, 4th Edition"*)

So the translation should be:

**她打扮得很精致。**

or

**她穿着很华丽。**

Answer (score 1):

'fancy' is a shortened form of fantasy, so in relation to manner or bearing it will always have at least a tinge of negativity, of someone imagining themself to be what he or she is not.

She is very fancy.

她真花俏。
She's rather gaudy.

她很时髦。
She is very fashionable

她打扮得花里胡哨。
She is gaudy.

Answer (score -1):

One of the results from Google Translate for fancy is 花俏

When a sentence isn't translated correctly, try to search each word alone and piece the meaning together from there

- She is very fancy -->  她很看中 (here Google translated fancy as a verb and is obviously wrong)

Try:

- She --> 她
- is--> 是
- very --> 非常
- fancy --> 花俏(n); 优等/花式的 (adj)

Since fancy here is an adjective, you might think the translation would be 她是非常优等 or 她是非常花式的, However, 优等 or 花式的 is not an adjective for human. They are for objects or moments e.g. 优等鋼材 (High-grade steel), 花式跳水(fancy diving)

> Meanwhile, [花俏](https://cd.hwxnet.com/view/ikpgjocofilffhga.html) as an adjective means:

> 艳丽漂亮：打扮花俏｜爱用花俏的词语。 (Gorgeous and beautiful: dress up fancy | love to use fancy words.)

"She is very fancy" should be translated as "她(是)非常花俏(的)" or "她(是)很花俏"(的).

*是 and 的 can be omitted*

Answer (score -1):

We usually say "她很是花枝招展".

Comment: It is necessary to clear "花枝招展" is a bit negative. I am not sure if "fancy" is a negative word.